# Why was a question marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

So I was looking through some SO questions, and I noticed that [Why have "while(1);" in XmlHttpRequest response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871505/why-have-while1-in-xmlhttprequest-response) was closed as a duplicate, but the question it linked to was newer than the one marked as duplicate. Why did this happen?

Comment: It's still a duplicate.

Comment: It's because the newer one has answers.

Comment: But why is it a duplicate if it was asked first, and why was the second one not marked as duplicate?

Comment: The second one could not have been marked as duplicate of the first, because the first has no answers. The original must have answers.

Comment: Note also that if the concern is a matter of "fairness," the original asker does not (to my knowledge) lose any of the rep gained from a question if it's marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was closed because although it was posted earlier, the post that is was closed as a duplicate of had more activity and it had answers posted (600+ votes on the question, 4 answers, 800+ votes on the accepted answer).  Although most questions don't have that much of a difference of activity, in this case the newer question has much more activity and as a result is a better reference for users looking for help.